# Multi-key operations must involve a single slot Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

we have issue to read multiple keys in redis cluster mode.

we using stack exchange redis .
i have gone through for same git issue
[Multi-key](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/838)

As there 4 option is suggested

1. use "hash tags" if the data is strongly related (this keeps related
   data in a single slot).
2. use individual StringGet.
3. we implement a new API that does a scatter/gather (would need to wait for this).
4. your code could manually groups by slots to perform multiple varadic gets.

do we have any update on point 3, or any other way to perform multi key operation in cluster mode .

Comment: "do we have any update on point 3" - You should as there (StackExchange.Redis)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your list of keys (by querying across all servers, for example) you can then group keys by their hash slot and send each group as a bulk command as follows:

```
var keyList = keys.GroupBy(k => _redisConnection.GetHashSlot(k));

foreach (var keyGroup in keyList) {
    // send each group to a bulk command
```